# Matlab: How to interact with a graph to define a range via GUIs

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm currently trying to make a GUI that will allow a user to select a range of x-values, limited to a set of predefined "markers" that can appear on the graph of some data.  The Matlab program has a bunch of data that's already delimited with some number of markers, and will ask the user to choose two of these markers as a start and stop point, and then continue from there.

My question is whether or not Matlab has a built-in function or object that will place some kind of interactive marker on the plot (preferably on the bottom of the graph so that it doesn't obscure the data) that the user can click on so that I can get a call-back function from it and see which marker the user chose (and also perhaps have the ability to change its color and such to represent its selection).

Preferably the answer will not involve any add-ons, but any answer and any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: You could use two scroll bars, one to select the lower value and one to select the higher value.

Comment: That is certainly a viable option, thank you!  However, I would prefer to make the interface based on the graph, if possible.  If I can't figure out how to do that, though, I will consider your response!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very simple example using [ginput](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html), which asks the user to select a starting and ending points from which to plot the data.

```
clear
clc
close all

x = 1:15*pi;

figure
plot(x,sin(x),'LineWidth',2);

uiwait(msgbox('Select a start and finish point'))

a = zeros(1,2);
[a,~] = ginput(2);

xStart = a(1);
xFinish = a(2);

set(gca,'XLim',[xStart xFinish],'XTick',round(xStart):1:round(xFinish))
```

Is it something like this you had in mind? Do you really need a callback or is this sufficient? If not could you elaborate on what kind of markers you would need?

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is similar to what I want, but I need to restrict the values of a(1) and a(2) to some preset values (I could of course just get a "general" area from the user, and choose the closest marker, but if possible I want to be a bit more clean than that).

You're right, I don't NEED a callback, I just thought that the answer would involve a GUI object.  In the end, I will be using these markers' x-values to truncate the data and continue processing it, but they really should be restricted to preset values.  Thank you again for your answer, it's a great place to start!

Comment: Ok great then I'll dig a bit into something more sophisticated :)

Comment: Well...honestly, it kind of depends on how buggy our setup will be...the answer to which is currently "quite".  There SHOULD only be 4, but I would like the system to be able to handle quite a lot.  However, if there are a lot grouped on top of each other, precision isn't a huge issue.  Being off by a few x-units isn't a big deal, so picking one marker instead of the one right next to it isn't a problem.  Thanks!